# Lock Windows to a specific app

Tags: windows, appsec

Is it possible, using some program or application, to lock Windows 7 so only a specific app can be used, for example Word, until a password is entered?

Comment: What you're talking about is called "Kiosk Mode". How you do it depends on your OS/Version. Google is your friend.

Comment: You could also use AppV or some per-app remote desktop type setup depending on your environment, please expand your question with more details.

Answer (score -1):

The use case you are describing is perfect for a White Listing application.  In the past I have use Savant Protection and have had good success.  Savant allows you to specify what applications are allowed to execute though either a configuration file or by "training" it.  Savant will take all of the white listed applications, calculate their hash values and stoarge location and place all of this information into an encrypted database.  Before an application is allowed to execute, savant compares the current state against the database.